# When to put self and when this in Ext-JS 4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Consider the example:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-static-method-getName

```
Ext.define('My.cool.Class', {
    constructor: function() {
        alert(this.self.getName()); // alerts 'My.cool.Class'
    }
});

My.cool.Class.getName(); // 'My.cool.Class'
```

What is the `self` referring to in this example?
How can I, in this documentation, know when to use `this` and when `self` and when `this.self`?
Why this is not working:

```
this.getName()
```

or

```
self.getName()
```

My thoughts about this are that self refers to the class of the object so the only reason I need to do this is because the getName() method is static so I'm (kinda) not calling it from object, but from class. Am I right? Am I? Ha? Ha? Am I? :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this.self` refers to the class object. It means that `this.self === My.cool.Class`. So you can instantiate new `My.cool.Class` object by invoking `new this.self()`.

The reason why `this.getName()` doesn't work is because in JS static properties/methods are not available in instance.

Example:

```
var Class = function(){};
Class.prototype = {};

Class.staticMethod = function(){ alert('static method'); };
Class.prototype.instanceMethod = function(){ alert('instance method'); };

var instance = new Class();

Class.staticMethod(); // works
Class.instanceMethod(); // doesn't work

instance.staticMethod(); // doesn't work
instance.instanceMethod(); // works
```

Also static properties/methods are not available in sub class even in static context.

Example:

```
Ext.define('One', {
    instanceMethod: function() { alert('Instance One'); }
});
Ext.apply(One, {
    staticMethod: function() { alert('Static One'); }
});


Ext.define('Two', {
    extend: 'One'
});


One.staticMethod(); // works
Two.staticMethod(); // doesn't work
```

The reason why `getName` method is available in `My.cool.Class` is because there are copied from `Ext.Base` class in `ExtClass.create` method (this class is private, it's not visible in API).
    ​

Comment: I understand it completely. Thank you very much. :D I'll mark this as "correct" answer. :)

Comment: +1 Super! I considered answering but new someone could explain this clearly :)

Answer (score 0):

this.self does not work for recursive static methods, to call recursively to a static method you just have to use this (i.e. this.myCurrentRecursiveMethod(params))